# How to generate a folder size report with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

On Linux, I can generate a CSV output with the following command

```
du -hs /home/*/imap/*/* | sort -rh | sed 's/\//\t/g' | awk '{print $5 " " $6 " " $1}' | sed 's/ /,/g'
```

This command outputs a CSV file with the following structuur:

```
 domain,username,userfoldersize
```

I am trying to get a similar output with PowerShell.

I found this code online, but it does not display sizes correct. Foldersizes over GB sizes, are still displayed in MB. Also, it goes to far in the subdirectory.

```
$startFolder = 'C:\path\to\mail\domain\user'

$colItems = (Get-ChildItem $startFolder | Measure-Object -property length -sum)
"$startFolder -- " + "{0:N2}" -f ($colItems.sum / 1MB) + " MB"

$colItems = (Get-ChildItem $startFolder -recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True} | Sort-Object)
foreach ($i in $colItems)
    {
        $subFolderItems = (Get-ChildItem $i.FullName | Measure-Object -property length -sum)
        $i.FullName + " -- " + "{0:N2}" -f ($subFolderItems.sum / 1MB) + " MB"
    }
```

I have a directory like this: `C:\path\to\mail\domain\user` and I want it to display the full path to the `user` folder, and display the `user` foldersize. In a human readable format. e.g.: 500MB, 5GB etc...

Comment: what report did you try that's failing?

Comment: Try `gci -Path C:\users\blade19899\Desktop -Recurse | measure -Sum Length).Sum`. Apparently MS has their own du available for download: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/du

Comment: @root , that gives me an error. And the `du` Windows equivalent is buggy, and doesn't display the folder size

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @root `Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.`. I removed the `)`, but it then just display count an not the subfolders. Tried it with a  `*`, but no luck.

Comment: I messed the copy/paste up. Needs an open parentheses. `(gci -Path C:\users\blade19899\Desktop -Recurse | measure -Sum Length).Sum`. I misunderstood the original post, this will not show subfolder sizes.

Comment: @root How can I display subfolders sizes?

Comment: Don't known of a good one-liner. This script should do it, run with `Get-FolderSize -Path C:\users\blade19899\Desktop`. https://herringsfishbait.com/2014/09/10/recursion-in-powershell-getting-the-size-of-sub-folders/ There are a ton of solutions for this online.

Comment: Instead of learning Powershell, you could use [Cygwin](https://cygwin.org): it puts at your disposal several commands, commonly found on Linux, which you might already be familiar with. Since your one-liner relies on `du`, `sort`, `sed` and `awk`, it should require little to no adaptations.

Comment: @simlev that is a last resort. Desktop installing Cygwin is fine, but this is a Windows server/

Comment: For questions involving a server, you might want to post on [serverfault](https://www.serverfault.com). I fail to see the issue with cygwin, but it certainly depends on corporate policies. Installing it as a portable app could be compliant in your case, but feel free to also explore one of the several alternatives, including [cmder](http://cmder.net).

Comment: @simlev , cmder worked. Cygwin was to buggy with `du`. Thanks! You can post that one as an answer, and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, it appears you are comfortable with the Linux command line. When on Windows, you don't necessarily have to ditch that knowledge and learn new commands: instead, you can leverage what you already know and continue using the familiar `bash`, `du`, `sort`, `sed` and `awk`.

**My suggestion** is:

1. employ [cygwin](https://cygwin.org) or [cmder](http://cmder.net) or a [similar](https://git-for-windows.github.io) [tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/commandline/wsl/about), in order to continue doing your stuff
2. learn [Powershell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell) to do new things

Note: sometimes a portable installation is the only way to go; in that case I'd recommend [cmder](http://cmder.net).